# How to create a map like the one that's there on ikman.lk

Tags: html, css, maps

I want to know how to create a map like the one that is there on [ikman.lk](http://ikman.lk/)

Comment: Has your wanting led to any research? Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This map created using [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG).

Here is a website with SVG's maps.

https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/